# Type of values in the WHERE ... IN ... clause

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have a question about Apex and SOQL. I've searched for an answer without success..
In a lot of examples and exercises about Apex and SOQL, I see that we use the WHERE... IN... clause of a SOQL query in a way that seems going against what it is written in the documentation. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) you can read that:

> ...You must supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field...

But I often read something like:

> ... WHERE Id IN Trigger.New

It is a fact that Trigger.new is of type 'List of sObject', so I am wondering how something that has a type 'ID' could match an sObject (that is an element of a list)...

I know it is working so I surely miss something.

Answer (score 6):

The `IN` logical operator works on collections, not singular values. Generally speaking, you do need to use a collection of the correct type. There are two exceptions to this, one of which you have stumbled upon. If you are querying on a relationship field, you can filter against a `List<SObject>` and it will check for any of the ids.

Another exception is the use of [Semi-Joins with IN and Anti-Joins with NOT IN](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semi_and_anti):

> You can query values in a field where another field on the same object has a specified set of values, using IN. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT Name FROM Account
> WHERE BillingState IN ('California', 'New York')
> ```
>
> In addition, you can create more complex queries by replacing the list of values in the IN or NOT IN clause with a subquery. The subquery can filter by ID (primary key) or reference (foreign key) fields. A semi-join is a subquery on another object in an IN clause to restrict the records returned. An anti-join is a subquery on another object in a NOT IN clause to restrict the records returned.

See also: [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com), where they are referred to as inner and outer joins.

Comment: Thanks it is clearer already. Just to be sure, in the case of the exception I've encountered, it is only working when matching IDs, isn't it? With another field such as Name it would produce an error, right?

Comment: Yes, you can only use `List<SObject>` as the filter value on a relationship field.

Comment: Just to add to it, dynamic SOQL knows to interpret a List/single value smartly, so you could avoid having IN even on a List, like the following:                                          List<Id> idList = new List<ID>{'0034000001zzzz','0034000001xxxx','0034000001fyyyy'};
List<Transaction__c> useIN = [Select id from Transaction__c where Placement__r.Employee__c in :idList];
List<Transaction__c> notUseIN = [Select id from Transaction__c where Placement__r.Employee__c = :idList];

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggyback and elaborate on Adrian Larson's answer, his SOQL statement is shorthand for

SELECT  Name
FROM    Account
WHERE   (BillingState = 'California',
OR      BillingState = 'New York,
OR      BillingState = 'Cincinnati')

==== translation ====

SELECT  Name
FROM    Account
WHERE   BillingState IN ('California','New York, 'Cincinnati')